# datagridview does not contain a definition for rowcount no accessible extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is  my code. this also applies to ColumnCount

```cs
var dgArray = new object[GridView1.RowCount, GridView1.ColumnCount + 1];

if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow i in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (i.IsNewRow) continue;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell j in i.Cells)
        {
            dgArray[j.RowIndex, j.ColumnIndex] = j.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably RowCount should be Rows.Count and same for column count. Your own code has it written the correct way.

Comment: Your if statement is not doing anything? if there is no rows in `GridView1` the code inside your foreach wont be executed

Comment: i have put the Rows.count ,but now the thing is it does transport data to Excel Spreadsheet

Comment: i have deleted the if statement ,,but now the data wont be imported to excell spreadsheet

Comment: if the your "rowcount no accessible extension method" question has been solved you should ask a new question detailing your new problem. You should take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask (if you ask a good question you will get a much better response)!...Take time to check if your new question has already being asked before too!